# Django/mod_wsgi looses session when passing to another url

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I got stuck with such kind of problem. I'm developing Django application hosted on Apache/mod_wsgi.

I replaced the standard Django authentication with **REMOTE_USER** authentication according to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/auth-remote-user/

I want to get valid user from Apache mod_auth_vas service (which I have ran on server), when user requests: **mysite.my/login**

So, my wsgi.conf is like below and I get prompt for authenticate user on **mysite.my/login**:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPythonHome /proj/tool/appl/portal/.venv
WSGIScriptAlias / /proj/tool/appl/portal/portal/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess portal python-path=/proj/tool/appl/portal/.venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages processes=1 threads=60 graceful-timeout=30 maximum-requests=1000 restart-interval=0 header-buffer-size=32768
WSGIProcessGroup portal
WSGISocketPrefix /tmp/wsgi
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog "/proj/weblogs/backendlogs/portal/apache/server1/wsgi/error.log"
CustomLog "/proj/weblogs/backendlogs/portal/apache/server1/wsgi/access.log" combined
#Timeout 600

<Directory /proj/tool/appl/portal/portal>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Files>
</Directory>

<Location "/login">
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit FileInfo Indexes
                AuthType VAS
                AuthVASUseBasic on
                AuthName "[ Enter Windows Password ]"
                Require valid-user
</Location>
```

**Prompt works okay:**
[How prompt looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OLeR.png)

Problem is that:

After login on the url: mysite.my/login Django session.user is correct (AuthenticatedUser) and SESSION_KEY **is not None value**:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index', views.index, name='index')
    url(r'^login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

views.py

```
def login(request, node):
    user = request.user
    session_key = request.session.session_key

    return HttpResponse("User is: {}<br />"
                        "SessionKey is: {}<br />"
                        .format(user, session_key))

def index(request, node):
    user = request.user
    session_key = request.session.session_key

    return HttpResponse("User is: {}<br />"
                        "SessionKey is: {}<br />"
                        .format(user, session_key))
```

mysite.my/login result of login is like:

[Result at url /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii194.png)

> User is: AuthenticatedUser
>   SessionKey is: pobrdspueqwopyu4ch6e07ziipi6zn2k

But after that when I go e.g. to mysite.my/index unexpectedly Django doesn't see
the User nor session_key like (Lost SESSION?):

mysite.my/index

[Result when go to another url than /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqiVB.png)

> User is:
>   SessionKey is: None

I have no idea why it happens. I tried to diable cahching, read session in templates but everything didn't work. Still ehen I go to another site than mysite.my/login the session disappears.

My settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
            ],
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ]
        }
    }
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # RemoteUser https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/auth-remote-user/
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend"
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db"

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portal.wsgi.application'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portal.urls'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

**My question is that:**

Why Django looses Session data when I go to another url site? 
When I run it locally by

> manage.py runserver

Session works properly.

Thanks in advance for help.

If I can correct something in question please inform. It's a first time I ask here.

Comment: Unrelated, but using ``threads=60`` would generally be a very bad idea. Python doesn't handle multithreading that well. Usually 3-5 threads per process at most is better, unless for some reason you have an exceptional I/O bound application.

Comment: The auth directives should be applied to the whole site, not just ``/login``.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I'll corect threads in wsgi.conf @GrahamDumpleton .

Anyway, I don't want to restrict  all site for only authenticated users. I wanted only to restrict e.g. comment and content editing for authentiaced ones. 

In my project it's not possible to simply create users in Django/Admin becayse my users/passwords are stored in external service (mod_auth_vas). 
Is there other way that I can authenticate user at url `/login` and store login information for Django session?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/auth-remote-user/ and sure you have applied all that correctly. You probably want ``PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware`` that it mentions at end.

Comment: `PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware` works for me. Thanks a lot for your help @GrahamDumpleton. Sorry for late respond but I was facing with migration of Django **1.8** which doesn't support `PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware` to newer Django **1.11**. I had too old stuff. Thanks again.